# How to include space or any special character in a batch file output txt file before certain texts?

Tags: batch-file, batch-processing

I am running a batch file using the command

```
for /R .\ %%f IN ("*.tab") DO (echo File: %%f & gdalsrsinfo -o wkt "%%f") >>U:\srsinfo.csv
```

The output is

```
File: D:\QAQC\Old\1M_AGSO_Railways_Aust.TAB
GEOGCS["unnamed",DATUM["North_American_Datum_1983",SPHEROID["GRS 80",6378137,298.257222101],TOWGS84[0,0,0,-0,-0,-0,0]],PRIMEM["Greenwich",0],UNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433]]
File: D:\RTXQAQC\Old\1M_AGSO_Roads_Aust.TAB
GEOGCS["unnamed",DATUM["WGS_1984",SPHEROID["WGS 84",6378137,298.257223563],TOWGS84[0,0,0,-0,-0,-0,0]],PRIMEM["Greenwich",0],UNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433]]
```

Now, i want the file name alone and before it should be in a single line. So that using texy -> columns i can separate the fields. To do so, will it be possible to include space or any special character before GEOGCS - Datum - Spehroid so that i can easily separate it using text -> columns option in excel

I prefer it in this format

```
1M_AGSO_Railways_Aust.TAB ***SPACE*** GEOGCS["unnamed",DATUM["North_American_Datum_1983" ***SPACE***SPHEROID["GRS 80",6378137,298.257222101] ***SPACE*** TOWGS84[0,0,0,-0,-0,-0,0]]
```

Basically before every parameter, i need a space to separate using text to columns option

Comment: It would be much clearer for us if you post additionally to the output you currently get also the output formatted like you want it.

Comment: I've edited the question. Don't know why Space has not been bolded & italicized

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Command **FOR** can be used to get output of a console application written to [stdout](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_streams) redirected to a loop or an environment variable for further processing.

I offer two solutions for getting a CSV file with the data of interest separated by horizontal tab characters.

Solution 1 uses comma as delimiter to split the line into the data of interest.

```
@echo off
set "Separator= "
if exist U:\srsinfo.csv del U:\srsinfo.csv
for /R .\ %%# in (*.tab) do (
    for /F "tokens=1-14 delims=," %%A in ('gdalsrsinfo.exe -o wkt "%%#"') do (
        echo %%~nx#%Separator%%%A,%%B%Separator%%%C,%%D,%%E%Separator%%%F,%%G,%%H,%%I,%%J,%%K,%%L
    )
) >>U:\srsinfo.csv
set "Separator="
```

**Note:** The character after equal sign in second line must be a horizontal tab character and not a space character as displayed by browser according to HTML standard.

As the data line contains much more commas then just those on which to insert the CSV separator, there are lots of tokens (strings assigned to loop variables) needed to get the desired output.

Solution 2 separates the data by the keywords.

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
set "Separator= "
if exist U:\srsinfo.csv del U:\srsinfo.csv
for /R .\ %%# in (*.tab) do (
    for /F "delims=" %%L in ('gdalsrsinfo.exe -o wkt "%%#"') do (
        set "DataRow=%%L"
        set "DataRow=!DataRow:,SPHEROID=%Separator%!
        set "DataRow=!DataRow:,TOWGS84=%Separator%!
        set "DataRow=!DataRow:,PRIMEM=%Separator%!
        for /F "tokens=1-3 delims=%Separator%" %%A in ("!DataRow!") do (
            echo %%~nx#%Separator%%%A%Separator%SPHEROID%%B%Separator%TOWGS84%%C
        )
    )
) >>U:\srsinfo.csv
endlocal
```

**Note:** The character after equal sign in third line must be a horizontal tab character.

This solution replaces a keyword and the comma left of a keyword by the separator and result is assigned to environment variable `DataRow`. After necessary separation was done, one more **FOR** command is used to get the row for the CSV file with keywords added again and with just the data of interest.

For understanding the used commands and how they work, open a command prompt window, execute there the following commands, and read entirely all help pages displayed for each command very carefully.

- `del /?`
- `echo /?`
- `endlocal /?`
- `for /?` ... explains also `%~nx#` (just name and extension of file without drive and path)
- `if /?`
- `set /?`
- `setlocal /?`

And take also a look on Microsoft article about [Using command redirection operators](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb490982.aspx).

Comment: Big thanks to you mate. Helped me a lot. Worked perfectly. I am using the first code